# NextJS with app router: handle authentication

Tags: authentication, jwt, next.js13

In NextJs, when using the App router, what's the best way to handle authentication?

Let's say that I have a cookie that contains a JWT token, and I want to redirect the user to the homepage, if the user is not logged in and try to access a page that needs to be logged in.

Where should I put this logic, in the middleware?

Where should I put this logic, in the middleware, or there is some better place?
Thanks in advance.

```
export default function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  const { pathname } = request.nextUrl;

  const jwt = request.cookies.get("Authorization");

  if (!jwt && pathname.includes('/some_private_url')) {
      // not logged in -> goto home
      request.nextUrl.pathname = `/`;
      return Response.redirect(request.nextUrl);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

put it on the root folder.

see https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/routing/middleware#convention

> Use the file `middleware.ts` (or `.js`) in the root of your project to define Middleware. For example, at the same level as `pages` or `app`, or inside `src` if applicable.